# error en reportico

Tags: php, yii2

Actualmente uso **yii2** y e instalado el módulo de **reportico** el cual es el [siguiente](http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/gettingstarted).

Lo he instalado sin problemas y todo bien, cuando entro al módulo y le doy a crear nuevo proyecto me sale lo siguiente

> Unable To Continue: Can't find report

y no me sale mas nada, hasta ahi llega, ya le di permisos a las carpetas

> {YII2_ROOT}/vendor/reportico/reportico/compnents/templates_c
>   {YII2_ROOT}/vendor/reportico/reportico/compnents/projects/admin

He investigado por internet y no he podido dar con una solución. 
Si alguien ha usado este módulo de reportes me podría ayudar se lo agradeceria bastante.

Comment: Puedes revisar esta liga, igual puede solucionarse con esto. http://www.reportico.org/swsite/site/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=45318

Comment: ah si yo lei en esa pagina, reenombre el archivo config.template a config.php como indican y me sale el error que le sale al chico osea el siguiente: Missing file: YII2APP\vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\reportico_adodb/drivers/adodb-n/a.inc.php
ADONewConnection: Unable to load database driver ''

Comment: Realizaste lo que comenta después? el debug